# Install Python 2.5 on RedHat/Centos

Tags: redhat, python

Current Python version is 2.4...

```
yum upgrade python
```

Gives

```
Could not find update match for python
```

Do I have to install from source?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to install from source, you can use the following:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.2/Python-2.5.2.tgz
tar fxz Python-2.5.2.tgz
cd Python-2.5.2
./configure
make
make install
```

This will install Python 2.5 as the command python2.5, as yum and other parts of CentOS require the old Python 2.4, so you will have two versions of Python installed.

```
/usr/bin/python - 2.4.3
/usr/bin/python2.5 - 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks - I hate having multiple versions of things - e.g. would like mod_python to use 2.5

Comment: Timmy's answer below could very well be more correct; a mere 'make install' will likely ruthlessly pummel your existing Python install and break your box.

Answer (score 10):

```
./configure 
make 
make install
```

The command should be the following (according to the README for 2.7)

```
./configure 
make
make altinstall
```

See the "Installing multiple versions" section in [the README](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/README?view=markup).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with ./configure

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

so, I installed these packages

```
yum install gcc make
```

then, it works ;)