# python version change

Tags: centos, python, mod-python

I am working on centOS 5 Server with python's version 2.4.3

Now i installed python 2.5 (got command from SF) from [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/24207/install-python-2-5-on-redhat-centos) as

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.2/Python-2.5.2.tgz
tar fxz Python-2.5.2.tgz
cd Python-2.5.2
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

then i executed command python -V
it says

```
Python 2.4.3
```

then i tried command to change it from this to 2.5 as i have syntax error in my file because of the lower version of python.

```
 python_select python-2.5.2
```

but it says

```
-bash: python_select: command not found
```

can any one please help me how to change it so that i can execute my .py file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
from __future__ import with_statement
```

on my python file then it took this path for execution because there was previous path set already. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute path:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.5 /path/to/your/script
```