# Install gettext-0.17-1.el5.i386.rpm on CentOS 5.8 i386 gives "/usr/bin/python is needed" error

Tags: python, centos5, yum, rpm, installation

I've removed yum by mistake. So, now I'm installing all the dependencies needed by yum manually. One of those is gettext-0.17-1.el5.i386.rpm and when I try to install it gives the following error,

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/python is needed by gettext-0.17-1.el5.i386
```

which is weird since I've installed python 2.6 already in the system.

```
#python -V
Python 2.6.8
#which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

So I copied /usr/local/bin/python to /usr/bin/python and even after that I'm getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Red Hat 5.x and derivatives rely very heavily on the provided Python 2.4. You can't remove it. Have you made attempt to do so? Also, rather than copying the binary to /usr/bin, you should symlink it.

Comment: @Aaron Copley I was getting errors when I tried to install reviewboard (reviewboard.org) using Python 2.4. So I removed it and installed Python 2.6. Also I tried creating symlink and that too din't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I was getting errors when I tried to install reviewboard (reviewboard.org) using Python 2.4. So I removed it and installed Python 2.6. Also I tried creating symlink and that too din't work.

Yum itself requires Python 2.4 among other Red Hat utilities. You're going to have a lot of problems related to the removal of Python 2.4. That error should probably more accurately read; `/usr/bin/python (Python 2.4) is needed by...`.

See this question: [Install Python 2.5 on RedHat/Centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/24207/install-python-2-5-on-redhat-centos). Also, another option is python26 is in EPEL.  I'm not sure how recent it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you removed the *system* Python package; yum is looking for the *package* which provides Python to be installed, not merely a Python binary. Reinstall the `python` package. And in the future, be very careful when removing packages.